# custom branch and bound on cplex or GAMS

Tags: cplex, c++, gams, callback, branch-and-cut

Does anyone have an idea how to create a custom B&B on CPLEX or GAMS? In my work, I need to add custom cuts on integer solutions in certain conditions by adding only one branch. Also, I need to get the optimal tableau of simplex of the relaxed problem to detect this conditions.

Is there any way to do that without going to do it manually?

I'm using C++.

Answer (score 1):

It seems BranchCallback function in cplex. I provide the introduction about BranchCallback on the official website and I did a very simple example by using VS C++ as well.

1. Cplex website
   https://www.ibm.com/docs/pt/icos/20.1.0?topic=classes-cplexcallbacksbranchcallback
2. my github link
   https://github.com/ytsao/MyBranchAndCut/blob/master/MyBranchAndCut/MyBranchAndCut.cpp

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i just run your example now, but i have not understand how it works ? what is "MyBranchGoal" and if you can explain what your branch do exactly to understand the code. Thanks again

Comment: For my code, since at that time, I also tried to understand how it works, I just refer the sample code on other websites. I just found the one that introduces it pretty well. https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/mathematik/discrete/manuals/cplex/doc/userman/html/moreUsing12.html

Comment: So, for me, I would imagine MyBranchandGoal is a function name to link with cplex engine. You can change any name to whatever you want, just be consistent with the below when you call solve.